# get password client from access token passport laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i use passport in laravel and after user verification i want to generate a token for them with refresh token . for get refresh token i have to send curl request with `password` grant_type . after generate access token i want to get `Password Grant Client`from database and pass it to my curl body . i fount this code snippet:

```
 $tokenId = (new Parser(new JoseEncoder()))->parse($token)->claims()->get('jti');
 $client = \Laravel\Passport\Token::find($tokenId)->client;
```

and the problem result of client variable is `Personal Access Client` not `Password Grant Client` and get this error because of its `personal type`:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Client authentication failed",
    "message": "Client authentication failed"
}
```

this is my code:

```
$token = $user->createToken(Config::get('auth.guards.api.token_name'))->accessToken;
        $tokenId = (new Parser(new JoseEncoder()))->parse($token)->claims()->get('jti');
        $client = \Laravel\Passport\Token::find($tokenId)->client;

        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        try {
            $response = $http->request('POST', url("/oauth/token"), [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => $oClient->id,
                    'client_secret' => $oClient->secret,
                    'username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password,
                    'scope' => '*',
                ],
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        }
```

how can i deal with this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. With OAuth there is an authorization server and the client. The authorization server (OAuth) grants tokens and the client receives those tokens and sends them. From the code snipped above it looks like you are both creating tokens and requesting tokens from the client? Or is the first 3 lines part of the authorization server?

Comment: @BernardWiesner i want to generate token in my api and send it back to client with its refresh token and for generate related refresh token i need to send a curl post request as exists in my code snippet . the question is what is the value of parameters of client_id and client_secret and how can i get achieve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For obtaining the `client_id` and `client_secret` for `Password Grant Client` you need to run the following command on your authorization server (OAuth server) as stated here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#creating-a-password-grant-client

```php
php artisan passport:client --password
```

The above command is not necessary to run if you already ran `passport:install`. The easiest way is to check your `oauth_clients` table for the column `password_client` there should be a row that has this value set to 1 (enabled).

It seems from your question that you are trying to obtain the `client_id` and `client_secret` programmatically from your client. This is not the correct way of doing it.
Basically after you run the above command to generate your `client_id` and `client_secret` you need to hard code them in your .env and use them in you CURL such as:

```php
$response = Http::asForm()->post('http://passport-app.test/oauth/token', [
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'client_id' => env('OAUTH_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'scope' => '*',
]);
 
return $response->json();
```

You can obtain your `client_id` and `client_secret` from the `oauth_clients` table. Just make sure to copy the values where the `password_client` column is set to 1.

There should not be any security concern if your client is storing these credentials in the backend and doing the CURL from the backend.

In the case you are trying to do this from a mobile app and you might not have a way to securely store the `client_id` and `client_secret`. In this case you should not be using the `Password Grant Client` flow but instead the `Authorization Code Grant with PKCE`: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#code-grant-pkce